# Search finder for all photos in a given folder?

Tags: macos, finder, graphics, search

Prior to iOS using the HEIC image format (I'm aware this can be turned off) I used to be able to search for all images in a given folder taken on my iPhone, by using the search feature of macOS finder and searching for all JPG files as below.

[image: screenshot of MacOS finder and searching for all JPEG images]

But now I can't do that so easily as there is a mixture of image formats. Is there a way I can search for "kinds = all photos"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type in "kind:Image" and hit enter. I got results for .png, .jpg, .svg, .NEF, .CR2 etc.